# AttributeError: module 'keras.applications' has no attribute 'VGG16'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

I'm trying to run code that is supposed to identify different types of image categories.
The code is of VGG16 and I have the following error.
Of course I tried to install and import directories (keras etc...)and the error still exists.
Would appreciate help.
Thanks.

This is the line of code that is marked

`vgg16 = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='data3/')`

And that's the error

`AttributeError: module 'keras.applications' has no attribute 'VGG16'`

Answer (score 2):

It should be `applications.vgg16.VGG16(...)`.

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 1):

I solved same issue with `from tensorflow.keras import applications` instead of `from keras import applications`

Answer (score 0):

```
from tensorflow import keras as K., along with 
from tensorflow.keras import applications
```

This can also help.